# SQL Server 2008 process list - Is this normal?

Tags: sql-server-2008, checkpoint

I'm very new to SQL Server, and just wondered if anyone could tell me if this process list is normal.

```
Wait Time | Last Wait Type      | dbid
55372252  | ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE | 1
55371504  | BROKER_TRANSMITTER  | 1
55371504  | BROKER_TRANSMITTER  | 1
55352380  | BROKER_EVENTHANDLER | 1
55351938  | KSOURCE_WAKEUP      | 1
36413691  | XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT  | 0
393368    | LOGMGR_QUEUE        | 0
393367    | CHECKPOINT_QUEUE    | 2
23258     | XE_TIMER_EVENT      | 0
```

The server has been rebooted several times a day ago, which is what I think has caused the checkpoint restore messages to come up, db id 1 is Master and db 2 is tempdb.

As I understand it the checkpoint is when I have dirty pages which get written to the disk, but should this operation be taking as long as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CHECKPOINT_QUEUE wait is associated with SPID 19 on my system, which is a system process. Like the Service Broker processes, the wait time is probably indicative of the process just sitting around waiting for something it needs to do, rather than some work performing poorly and grinding for long periods. This is actually fairly common with system processes (SPID <= 45, from the looks of it), so I wouldn't worry too much about high wait times on any of those (especially if the thread status is "sleeping" for all of them, which they are for me).